# computer and organization and architecture hint

Tags: architecture, organization, opcode

a computer has 128 operations having opcodes to be executed with 512000 addresses (32-bit word).
How many bits required for 1 address instruction?How many bits required for 2 address instruction?

I just want hints to solve it because i don't understand what to do. I don't know what's the relation between opcodes and the number of address instruction, so if you clarify it to me i'll be gratefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think that a vital piece of information is missing in your question:**

How many operations take 1 operand, and how many operations take 2 operands?

**Suppose 97 operations take 1 operand, and 31 operations take 2 operands:**

- In the first group we have:

  - Operation length = 7 bits
  - Operand length = 19 bits (check the binary representation of 512000)
  - Total length = 7 + 19 = 26 bits
- In the second group we have:

  - Operation length = 5 bits
  - Operand length = 19 bits (check the binary representation of 512000)
  - Total length = 5 + 19*2 = 43 bits

And of course, you will have to define the operations in a manner that will allow the CPU to translate them without ambiguities (for example, `1000011...` can be a 7 bit operation, or it can be a 5 bit operation with `11...` as the first operand).

Comment: thanks alot, i only wanted hints and these are quite suffecient

Comment: No problem, you're welcome; please see the small supplemental at the end of the answer...